# SearchUi.orgHasAccessToSearchUiPages error

Tags: visualforce, lookup, error

I'm seeing a strange error today. Our org has a visualforce page where guest users insert a record. One of the fields for this record is a lookup. We allow these users to use the spyglass to search for the lookup record. today when the users click the spyglass, the new window that open displays a "Not Authorized Error". when logging in as admin preview, we get the error "SearchUi.orgHasAccessToSearchUiPages" putting this into google gives zero results.  The strangest thing is that we have not updated this page in months. Did something change with Spring 19 or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding "Search Pages" to the Site Standard Pages, but I would still like to know if anyone came across this change in the change notes for Spring 19